# Finding tuples in table with varying number of items per tuple

Tags: sql, h2, relational-division

I have a long table with three columns:

`ID, Type, Plan No`

and I am trying to find "ID"s where I have exactly the same combination of "Type"s associated with different "Plan No"s, but only these.

In the source table below the second ID (183217760) has three different associated types (S39905028, S39905133, S39905242) with three different "Plan No"s. The first ID (183217488) will not qualify, because the "Plan No" 300 is missing the second "Type".

The function should therefore return something like

```
183217760   200, 300, 400
183218746   200, 300
183218747   200, 300
183219126   200, 300
etc.
```

Doing a join will not work because I do not know how many lines will be combined. The source data is huge and there are potentially tuples with 20 or more items.

Here is the source table:

```
ID          Type        Plan No
183217488   S39905038   200
183217488   S39905133   200
183217488   S39905133   300
183217760   S39905028   200
183217760   S39905028   300
183217760   S39905028   400
183217760   S39905133   200
183217760   S39905133   300
183217760   S39905133   400
183217760   S39905242   200
183217760   S39905242   300
183217760   S39905242   400
183218106   S39905301   200
183218746   S39905028   200
183218746   S39905028   300
183218746   S39905133   200
183218746   S39905133   300
183218747   S39905028   200
183218747   S39905028   300
183218747   S39905133   200
183218747   S39905133   300
183219126   S39905028   200
183219126   S39905028   300
183219126   S39905133   200
183219126   S39905133   300
183219924   S39905028   200
183219924   S39905133   200
183219924   S39905133   300
183220269   B39910001   200
183220269   S39905012   200
183220269   S39905133   200
183220269   S39905301   200
183220271   B39910001   200
183220271   S39905012   200
183220271   S39905133   200
183220271   S39905301   200
```

Thanks a bunch for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how efficient this will be with H2, but the following seems to work with your sample data:

```
with plan_counter as (
  select id, type, count(distinct plan_no) as plan_count
  from plans
  group by id, type
), type_counter as (
  select id, plan_no, count(distinct type) as type_count
  from plans
  group by id, plan_no
), combined as (
  select pc.id, pc.type, tc.plan_no, pc.plan_count, tc.type_count
  from plan_counter pc
    join type_counter tc on tc.id = pc.id
)
select c1.id, group_concat(distinct c1.plan_no order by c1.plan_no separator ',') as plans
from combined c1
where not exists (select *
                  from combined c2
                  where c2.id = c1.id 
                    and c2.plan_count <> c2.type_count)  
group by c1.id
order by c1.id;
```

Here is an online example: http://rextester.com/WKT8701 
(The above uses Postgres, but apart from using `string_agg()` instead of `group_concat` it is the same)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem will be much more efficient using a procedural algorithm.

Even though I'm sure you can do it with SQL, it will become horrible slow to try it. You better use SQL to retrieve the rows in an orderly manner and process/filter it in your application.